# Using NETStandard2.0 dll with asp.net running in IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, iis-express, .net-standard

How (the hell) do I use a NETStandard2.0 dll with asp.net ?

I got a asp.net 4.5 web application that should use a NETStandard2.0 (Roslyn compiler)

FWIU I won't be able to run it on 4.5, I should first upgrade to 4.6.1 (fine it won't fit on our production servers)
But that's not enough I should install NetCore2.0 SDK.
OK.

Now I create a NETStandard2.0 project with  a reference to the nuget  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Csharp.

The web application compiles just fine but at runtime it fails with a missing dll Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Csharp.dll version 2.4.

It looks like it's because the NETStandard2.0 won't export the lib in nuget to the /bin output.

The solution seems to be adding a

> < CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true< /CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>

to the csproj.

When I do that, the csproj is not valid anymore (CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies under Project is unknown)

What Do i need
A) to get all the needed nuget dlls in the /bin of my NETStandard2.0 project
or
B) to make IIS express clever enough to get the nuget dll which are somewhere () on my disk.

<sub>How far am I to get a running web app with a NETStandard2.0 dll ?

Why is it so frustrating ?

Aren't nuget and NETStandard2.0 supposed to ease the life of dev ?

Why do I have to dig all the informations from the Internet and are not in my xxxx $ VS2017 ?</sub>

Comment: Before getting yourself frustrated more, why csnnot you get started from an official sample project Microsoft published at GitHub? I wonder why you shouldn’t get all information from the internet today, unless you are 100 years old and have difficulty to learn.

Comment: because the so called dll hell was a pleasure comparing to the nuget hell. Because MS publish some dll only for NETStandard2.0. Because VS2017 was working OOB some years ago and you rarely have to edit csproj by hand and you didn't have to learn where are the caches for this or that. Because I'd like to focus on dev rather than guessing on how to configure this black box.

Answer (score 0):

The property should be in a propertygroup

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Now there is a new dll missing System.ValueTuple which requires FW 4.7. Great